# Data response not able to map in react js app

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to create a eCommerce website. For that I have used a url endpoint to map the data.

http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1

Well, the second level of subcategories, I'm able to implement successfully, but for the third level of category, I'm not able to render perfectly

I'm sending the screenshot of the json response.

[image]

And this is what I have implemented till now, the screen shot.

[image]

As you can see, from the screenshot, I'm able to implement the top navigation category and even under it. But there is one more sub level of category-- e.g: under girls section, there are more sub categories which I'm unable to implement.

My code for the same:

topNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}> 
          <a className="dropbtn ">

          {navList.name}

          <ul className="dropdown-content">
          <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView}/> 
          </ul>

          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

subMenu.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import SubListMenu from './subListMenu';


    class SubMenu extends Component {
        render() {
            const {below} = this.props;
            return below.map(sub => {

                return (

                         <li key={sub.uniqueID}> 
                         <a>
                         {sub.name}
                         <ul>
                         <SubListMenu subBelow={this.props.below}/>
                         </ul>
                         </a>
                         </li>

                )
            })

        }

    }

    export default SubMenu;
```

subListMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SubListMenu extends Component {

        render() {
            const {subBelow} = this.props;
            console.log(subBelow)
            return subBelow.map(subl => {

                return (

                 <li key={subl.uniqueID}> <a>{subl.name}</a></li>



                )
            })

        }

    }

    export default SubListMenu;
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue. I don't know where I'm getting it wrong. I would grateful if someone could guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need is the recursive call to the component. So for example, for the third level you can again call the `SubMenu` something like this. this will again call the `Submenu` component and bind your third level (not just third 4,5... etc).

Note: I have not tested this code.

```
return subBelow.map(subl => {

            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <li key={subl.uniqueID}> <a>{subl.name}</a></li>
                    {subl.catalogGroupView !== undefined && <SubMenu below={subl.catalogGroupView} />}
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        });
```

Comment: It's working fine now. I have put the recursive call in the second component itself and it's rendering. Thank you so much.